# Netsuite: Live Field Update When Transaction Load

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Currently we have an implementation in place which uses a Replenish location as well as a Pick (readily available) location for stock.

The Pick location is set as available stock. The Replenish location is set as unavailable due to time restraints moving stock to Pick.

Our guys need to be able to see a combination of the Pick and Replenish stock location quantities to see what they can sell overall. I am struggling to update a custom column field with this calculation on transactions on a View state intermittently.

Most of the time I am able to run a before load user event script and it updates line values then proceeds to reload the page if any changes have occurred to the record (using Netsuite's navigation function).

For some reason, sometimes an error occurs of RCRD_HAS_BEEN_CHANGED when submitting the changed record before page reload. I assume this is because the back end of Netsuite is still processing the record submit when the reload occurs.

I have attempted using a wait timer to wait for a response from the submitrecord function before reloading but this error still occurs

Comment: Perhaps a non-stored field is a better approach in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The "RCRD_HAS_BEEN_CHANGED" error means that when your script tried to save the record, it has been changed since the last time your script loaded the record. For example:

```
User A edits the record --> script loads the record into memory
User B edits the record --> script loads the record into memory

User B is done with the record --> script saves the record successfully
User A is done with the record --> RCRD_HAS_BEEN_CHANGED error thrown by script
```